# select (get) article if no comment

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get an article if it doesn't have a comment (ex. where count(articleId) = 0 ). 
My sql query is below. How should I modify it?

```
select comment.*, article.title from article
left join comment on comment.articleid=article.articleid where article.catid=5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are quite close.  You just need to check for no matches:

```
select a.title
from article a left join
     comment c
     on c.articleid = a.articleid
where a.catid = 5 and c.articleid is null;
```

I made a few changes to your query:

- I removed the comments columns from the `select`.  If there is no match, why have a bunch of `NULL` values.
- I added table aliases (as abbreviations).  These make the query easier to write and to read.
- I added the condition that there is no match in the `comment` table.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `NOT EXISTS` instead of joining th two tables:

```
SELECT * FROM article a WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT articleid FROM comments c WHERE c.articleid = a.articleid)
```